# foreach my $var (@list) -- $var is a reference?

Tags: perl, foreach, perlsyn

So, I never knew this and I want to get some clarifcation on it.  I know if you do

```
foreach (@list){
```

if you change $_ in that loop it will affect the actual data. But, I did not know that if you did

```
foreach my $var1 (@list){
```

If you changed $var1 in the loop it would change the actual data. :-/  So, is there a way to loop over @list but keep the variable a read-only copy, or a copy that if changed will not change the value in @list?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`$var` is aliased to each item in turn.

See http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Foreach-Loops

> If any element of LIST is an lvalue, you can modify it by modifying VAR inside the loop. 
>   Conversely, if any element of LIST is NOT an lvalue, any attempt to modify that element 
>   will fail. In other words, the foreach  loop index variable is an implicit alias for each 
>   item in the list that you're looping over.

Answer (score 10):

Easiest way is just to copy it:

```
foreach my $var1 (@list) {
    my $var1_scratch = $var1;
```

or

```
foreach my $var1 ( map $_, @list ) {
```

But if $var1 is a reference, $var1_scratch will be a reference to the same thing.
To be really safe, you'd have to use something like Storable::dclone to do a deep copy:

```
foreach my $var1 ( @{ Storable::dclone( \@list ) } ) {
}
```

(untested).  Then you should be able to safely change $var1.  But it could be expensive if
@list is a big datastructure.

Comment: Be careful, $var1 is not a reference, but an alias. See the difference :

my  $var2=\$list[0]; print "$var2\n";

displays  SCALAR(0x8171880)

Comment: @wazoox: He meant if $var1 contained a reference, e.g. if @list contained a bunch of HASH refs. Even if you break the aliasing, you still have another copy of a reference to the same thing.

Answer (score 4):

It is an alias, not a reference.  If you want to create your own aliases (outside of for) you can use [Data::Alias](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Data-Alias/lib/Data/Alias.pm).

Comment: Umm... +0. That's +1 for the alias/reference clarification and -1 for giving instructions on doing the opposite of what the OP asked for. (Creating an alias as opposed to breaking aliasing.)

Comment: @Michael Carman ysth had already given the right answer, I was just pointing out that it is possible to create your own aliases.

Answer (score 3):

The only difference between these loops:

```
foreach (@array) { ... }
foreach my $var (@array) { ... }
```

is the loop variable. The aliasing is a function of `foreach`, not the implicit variable `$_`. Note that this is an *alias* (another name for the same thing) and not a *reference* (a pointer to a thing).

In the simple (and common) case, you can break the aliasing by making a copy:

```
foreach my $var (@array) {
    my $copy = $var;
    # do something that changes $copy
}
```

This works for ordinary scalar values. For references (or objects) you would need to make a deep copy using [Storable](http://perldoc.perl.org/Storable.html) or [Clone](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Clone), which could be expensive. Tied variables are problematic as well, [perlsyn](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Foreach-Loops) recommends avoiding the situation entirely.

Comment: or Clone::More or Clone::Fast

Comment: or make a copy in the foreach with for my $var (() = @array)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to force the variable to be by-value instead of by-reference in the foreach statement itself.  You can copy the value of `$_` though.

```
#!/usr/perl/bin
use warnings;
use strict;

use Data::Dumper;

my @data = (1, 2, 3, 4);

print "Before:\n", Dumper(\@data), "\n\n\n";

foreach (@data) {
    my $v = $_;
    $v++;
}

print "After:\n", Dumper(\@data), "\n\n\n";

__END__
```

Comment: Where you say `my $v = shift;` you mean `my $v = $_;`.

Comment: @Dave Hinton corrected the error. @Sukotto try printing $v in the body of your loop as you originally wrote it to see your error.

Comment: Yes, I meant `my $v = $_;` :-(

Answer (score 1):

Make a copy of @list in the for statement:

```
foreach my $var1 (() = @list) {
  # modify $var without modifying @list here
}
```